# Getting keys from typed dictionary fails where implicit dictionary succeeds

Tags: typescript

I have the following type definition:

```
export const countries = {
  US: {
    name: "United States"
  },
  UK: {
    name: "United Kingdom"
  }
};

export type CountryCodes = keyof typeof countries;
```

With this definition CountryCodes is successfully returning a type of: `"US" | "UK`

However, I want to type the the property values in `countries` so I instead use the following type definition:

```
export interface IDictionary<T = any> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

export interface ICountry {
  name: string;
  population?: number;
}

export const countries: IDictionary<ICountry> = {
  US: {
    name: "United States"
  },
  UK: {
    name: "United Kingdom"
  }
};
```

Now, however, the `CountryCode` typing is defined as `string | number`.

How can I get the stronger typing I want on the `countries` structure while maintaining the `CountryCodes` type definition?

Answer (score 2):

**By defining your keys upfront**

This solution requires you to define string literals used as keys in your dictionary in advance. Note: if none are provided, just a `string` is used as the default type parameter and your `IDictionary` behaves just like before.

```
type IDictionary<V, K extends string = string> = {
  [Index in K]: V
}

type CountryCodes = "US" | "UK"

export const countries: IDictionary<ICountry, CountryCodes> = {
  US: {
    name: "United States"
  },
  UK: {
    name: "United Kingdom"
  }
};
```

**By using an extra function call**

In this solution, we create a factory function which makes sure whatever we give it meets certain criteria.

```
const assert = <T>() => <U extends T>(argument: U): U => argument;
```

Usage:

```
const assertCountries = assert<IDictionary<ICountry>>();

const countries = assertCountries({
  US: {
    name: "United States"
  },
  UK: {
    name: "United Kingdom"
  },
});

type CountryCodes = keyof typeof countries; // "US" | "UK"
```

**By dropping the type definition**

Sometimes it's just easier to *not* use a type definition and trust TypeScript to infer the type of your object literal. In this approach, we start data-first and — if need be — create types based on your data, just like you did in the beginning.

In order to get the desired type-safety, we shift the responsibility to the consumers of your data. Here, `foo` makes sure its argument conforms to the desired shape.

```
const countries = {
  US: {
    name: "United States"
  },
  UK: {
    name: "United Kingdom"
  }
};

type CountryCodes = keyof typeof countries; // "US" | "UK"

function foo<T extends IDictionary<ICountry>>(countries: T): void {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: On the surface I liked the "By using an extra function call" approach because it gives both functional goals: (1) provide a simple dictionary who's value is constrained by ICountry and (2) be able to pull out the keys without defining them externally. When I tried this, however, it appears the Dictionary values are _not_ constrained by ICountry.

Comment: Your first example certainly works but I'm trying to keep it DRY so the requirement of defining keys externally and then again internally in the dictionary is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: And yes the last example works for the functional goal of picking off the keys in the object but it fails to ensure that the values in the `countries` object are typed correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by _values are not constrained by ICountry_? IntelliSense works fine, values must extend the `ICountry` interface. See [TypeScript Playground](https://links.wtf/HV81). If you mean your values are allowed to have excess properties, then that's [another topic](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).

Comment: yes I had tested using additional properties and it was allowing that